# How to get the product list data through magento 2 API

Tags: magento2.4.0

[image: This is the screenshot]

when i am calling API through Postman. Only sku, position and category id is coming but How i want more detail like product name price and other details

Answer (score 2):

Try with below

```
GET <host>/rest/<store_code>/V1/products/"sku_here"?fields=name,sku,price,extension_attributes[category_links,stock_item[item_id,qty]]
```

To get all attributes of product = `http://localhost.com/index.php/V1/products/{sku}`

Comment: First of all I thank you so much. I am new here and sorry for any wrong discussion. But I want to know - <host>/rest/<store_code>/V1/products/"sku_here" by this i can fetch detailed data for one product but i have to fetch product list by category id. So How can I do this? Thanks in advance